# Create interactive customized HTML Maps in QGIS 3?

Tags: qgis-3

I am planning to create this as an html page using QGIS. What is the best approach to go about the same?

****Specific details required - How to create Bubbles of varying size based on attribute?**** For example Increase bubble size based on increasing Total Loss

[image]